Office Click To Run installer issue when run from service
I have written a windows service in .net. This Windows service will receive instructions from another computer.
The service will copy installers from a file share to the machine and execute them. For testing, I manually copied the installer to the specified install folder on the local PC (C:\Working\Deploy\OfficeInstall), and the service  executes setup.exe to install Microsoft Office 365, using a 60 second timer that executes the file to install.

I have a correctly configured XML file for the installation.
I have tested this service by installing other apps like DropBox and Bitwarden. It works                                                                          perfectly fine.
The service runs with LocalSystem elevation.
I execute the command in my application via the Start-Process command. It executes with LocalAdmin details for the StartProcessInfo.
My command line arguments are: /C "C:\Working\Deploy\OfficeDeploy\setup.exe" /configure "C:\Working\Deploy\OfficeDeploy\ACS_365_Apps.xml"
Intune Endpoint has an exception for Defender, for the Deploy service I'm using.

This works fine when I execute it from a command line that opens on the system with Admin privileges, however when run from the service it: [] .
Any ideas? It is the offline ClickToRun installer that has this issue. All other .exe apps install fine.

Have you considered reviewing the log files? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/installation/office-setup-issues

Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately is doesn't seem to get as far as that. I can log files when I install it by double clicking on the installer, so it is outputting logs.

You're trying to say you are running an executable and nothing happens, no std out or error. You need to run ProcMon to identify what is happening. Probably useful to include the command line used.

We're also assuming this is being tested on a normal network connection and doesn't require a proxy.

Hi Greg, It's all been done locally on the machine. I'm in a building with 100 odd folks, so there is firewalls and other security measures in place. Commandline args are in the original post. It's a windows service that is running the executable using elevated permissions (local admin). i'm writing the output of the StartProcess used to the Event logs in windows. It doesn't show anything to indicate a failure. My guess is it might be some kind of prompt. Thanks for the ProcMon suggestion!

So, I figured this out. My application uses Process-Start to execute the Setup.exe. My process is set to wait until the process is finished. It seems like when the setup.exe is run, it launches additional processes to kick start the installation. As my Process is informed that setup.exe has finished it's part, it terminates the Process, which kills the whole process. Adding a delay timer allows the setup to finish properly.
I'm currently looking into how to determine when the setup has completely finished, but hopefully this will save someone days of frustration.
